# Как сделать границу таблицы?

Tags: html, css, html5

Есть таблица нужно после каждого тега: "tr", сделать линию, или границу(бордер). Но , что-то не получается... Подскажите как правильно сделать ?

```css
table {
 width: 100%; 
 background: white; 
 color: #000;
 border-spacing: 1px; /* Расстояние между ячейками */ 
}


td, th {
 background: #FFF;
 padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
   }

tr:nth-child(1) {
 border-style: double; /* Стиль рамки вокруг параграфа */
    border-width: 3px 7px 7px 4px; /* Толщина границы */
    padding: 7px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
 
 
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
 
border-style: double; /* Стиль рамки вокруг параграфа */
    border-width: 3px 7px 7px 4px; /* Толщина границы */
    padding: 7px; /* Поля вокруг текста */ 
 
}
```

```html
          <table>
   <tr><th>Title & Description 1</th><th>date</th>  <th>who</th></tr>
   <tr> <td>Ячейка 3</td><td>Ячейка 4</td>   </tr> 
   </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        background: white;
        color: #000;
        border-spacing: 1px;
    }
    td, th {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
</style>
```